# React with Apollo GraphQL subscriptions return value

Tags: graphql, publish-subscribe, apollo, react-apollo

I am working with Apollo GraphQL and am struggling to get the publish aspect of the pubsub down. Here is what I have:

Publish:

```
    const tst = { string1: 'hi', string2: 'hello' };

    pubsub.publish("sub", tst);
```

GraphQL Subscription

```
subscription ($Id: Int!) {
   test(Id: $Id){
      string1
      string2
   }
}
```

When I try this in graphiql, it just returns [Object] [Object] which signals to me something went wrong. Although I can not find the error code. If I change the two to this:

Publish:

```
pubsub.publish("sub", tst: 'hi');
```

GraphQL Subscription

```
subscription ($Id: Int!) {
   test(Id: $Id)
}
```

GraphiQL will return 'hi' when the publish is trigger. Why can I not return the first setup?

EDIT

Here is the schema:

```
type Test {
    string1: String
    string2: String
}
```

Here is the Subsciption Schema

```
test(Id: Int!): Test
```

Comment: Do you have the matching GraphQL schema?  What type is the field `test`?

Comment: @DavidMaze I added it to the question above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer. I was incorrectly publishing.

It should have use test instead of tst in the options arugment:

```
pubsub.publish("sub", { test: tst });
```